# perf4j LogParser returning empty file

Tags: log4j, perf4j

I am trying perf4j for the first time today.  I have generated a log file through a log4j appender but when I parse the log file to generate performance statistics, I get an empty output file.  Here is my log file (perfStats.log):

> Performance Statistics   2013-07-16 15:29:00 - 2013-07-16 15:30:00 Tag
>   Avg(ms)         Min         Max     Std Dev       Count
>
> Performance Statistics   2013-07-16 15:30:00 - 2013-07-16 15:31:00 Tag
>   Avg(ms)         Min         Max     Std Dev       Count
>
> Performance Statistics   2013-07-16 15:31:00 - 2013-07-16 15:32:00 Tag
>   Avg(ms)         Min         Max     Std Dev       Count
>
> Performance Statistics   2013-07-16 15:32:00 - 2013-07-16 15:33:00 Tag
>   Avg(ms)         Min         Max     Std Dev       Count
>   annotatedDBCall
>   14.6           6          38        11.8           5 
>   codeBlock1
>   26.5          14          63        17.7           6
>
> Performance Statistics   2013-07-16 15:33:00 - 2013-07-16 15:34:00 Tag
>   Avg(ms)         Min         Max     Std Dev       Count

I have tried numerous variations on:

```
java -jar ../lib/perf4j-0.9.16.jar -f csv -o aaa.log -r -t 1000000 perfStats.log
```

I have varied the output, time slice and format to no avail.  Just an empty output file each time.  Maybe I have the wrong concept of what this command is for.  Any help would be appreciated.  I am using Fedora Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I misread the Developers Guide for perf4j . . . I don't need to run this command!